# Как рассчитать остаток шагов до числа

Tags: javascript

Как рассчитать шаги до определенных чисел?
Есть массив чисел к примеру:

```
var end = 25,
    arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i <= end; ++i) {
    arr.push(i);
}
```

От `0` до `25`.
И есть переменные:

```
var stop = 8, // на каком числе необходимо остановится
    step = 5; // сколько шагов до остановки
```

Как сделать так, чтобы был проход к примеру несколько раз по всем числам и потом рассчитывался `step`.
То есть число шагов до `stop`.

То есть к примеру остановились на `13`, все правильно, до `8` как-раз `5` шагов, но как это узнать?
При этом, нужно сделать эти `5` шагов в отдельном цикле, что-ли, чтобы они были `5` шагов, `5` раз чтобы вывелись числа от `13` до `8` к примеру.

Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: =___= пять шагов - начиная откуда? Что значит "расчитать step", если он и так уже объявлен?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, Ну вот если поставить числа по кругу, от 0 до 25.и бегать по ним бесконечно и в один прекрасный момент нужно будет совершить остановку на `stop` используя `step` - шаги, которые останутся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось банально и просто.

```
if((-step === (current - stop) || step === (current - stop))) {
    //.......
}
```

Странно, что никто не знал ответ на вопрос.
Бесполезный ресурс - это еще раз было утверждено.

Answer (score 0):

for(i=0; i <= end; i++)

- i = 0 с чего начинаем
- i <= end когда заканчиваем (здесь - достигли end)
- i++ шаг итерации (здесь +1)

Т.е 0 будет увеличиватся на 1 пока не достигнет end.

Как ваше условие подставить непонятно step и stop, на каком шаге остановка и сколько шагов до остновки - взаимосключающие условия.

Чисто по смыслу step может быть шагом итерации тогда stop это end

Comment: Вопрос прочитайте, прежде чем отвечать.